# How do I Compile a Visual Basic program for Mac computers using Visual Studio 2017 for Windows

Tags: vb.net

How do I Compile a Visual Basic program for Mac computers using Visual Studio 2017 for Windows?  I developed a Visual Basic Craps game program on Visual Studio 2017 for Windows.  I want to compile a version that will run on a Mac computer.  How do I do that?

Comment: If you wrote it in .net core it'll just work i the mac has .net core installed. If you wrote it in .net std then install mono on the mac and it'll probably work

Answer (score -2):

use the Visual Studio Code for macOS
https://code.visualstudio.com/